# How do I kill zombie/phantom scheduler jobs in laravel forge?

Tags: laravel, cron, laravel-forge

I'm using laravel forge, however I'm seeing processes that I set up in scheduler continue even after I've removed them from scheduler. How do I kill them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sudo vi /etc/crontab`

And delete all the jobs you no longer want